# Combining multiple queries in Access so that the data is displayed in different fields within a single table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two queries which I want to join together. `Union`option will not work as I want the values to be displayed in different fields. The 1st query is

```
 SELECT Outage.DISTRICT, Count(Outage.DISTRICT) AS CountOfDISTRICT
 FROM Outage LEFT JOIN [Site ID gets generated] ON Outage.[Site ID]=[Site ID gets     generated].[Site ID]
 GROUP BY Outage.DISTRICT;
```

The 2nd query is

```
SELECT Outage.DISTRICT, Count(Outage.[Site ID]) AS [CountOfSite ID]
FROM Outage
GROUP BY Outage.DISTRICT;
```

I tried the below code but it is giving syntax error (missing operator) in the 1st query

```
SELECT Outage.DISTRICT,
(SELECT  Count(Outage.[Site ID]) AS [CountOfSite ID] FROM Outage),
(SELECT  Count(Outage.DISTRICT) AS CountOfDISTRICT FROM Outage LEFT JOIN [Site ID gets generated] ON Outage.[Site ID]=[Site ID gets generated].[Site ID])
GROUP BY Outage.DISTRICT;
```

It would be very helpful if answer is also given with an explanation, as I am quite new to access and trying to learn it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two queries together to get their columns side-by-side:

```
select
  sq1.DISTRICT
, sq1.CountOfDISTRICT
, sq2.[CountOfSite ID]
from (
  ... your first query here ...
) as sq1
inner join (
  ... your second query here ...
) as sq2
on sq1.DISTRICT = sq2.DISTRICT
```

The thing to remember is that unions are for joining tables/queries *vertically,* while joins are for joining them horizontally.

Comment: Thanks friend it worked.#Respect. By the way can you tell me more about 'JOINS',basically their difference

Comment: @Soumyajit - sure, there's a good description here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins/448080#448080